# How does PrimeFaces detect the browser?

Tags: internet-explorer, primefaces, user-agent

1. How does PrimeFaces handle browser detection? Does it rely on jQuery to do that? Does it use the User Agent String?
2. How is prime-faces handling the [IE user-agent updates as discussed here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/01/09/the-internet-explorer-8-user-agent-string-updated-edition.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primefaces relies on jQuery, there are a few (I found 8) conditional executions based on the browser.

A function that check if it's IE and if the version matches the parameter (eg `isIE(9)` :

```
isIE: function (a) {
    return ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) == a)
},
```

A condition that checks for IE 6 or 7 :

```
if ($.browser.msie && /^[6,7]\.[0-9]+/.test($.browser.version)) {
    this.panel.parent().css("z-index", PrimeFaces.zindex - 1)
}
```

A condition that checks for IE with a version lower than 9 :

```
if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) < 9) {
    b.trigger("change")
}
```